# attributes given to getVaList are not displayed in the Crashlytics log files

Tags: ios, crashlytics, crash-log

I am new to using Crashlytics. I had started exploring use logging and created a sample ios project to test it. I am able to see the first parameter of the CLSLogv command but missing the second parameter

Example:
CLSLogv("Button1", getVaList([1,2,3]))

"Button1" is visible in log file but [1,2,3] is misssing

---

Unable to see the second attribute given to the getVaList in the log. [image]

```
import UIKit
import Crashlytics

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        let button = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: 100, height: 30)
        button.setTitle("Crash", for: [])
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.crashButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button)
        CLSLogv("Button1", getVaList([1,2,3]))
        write(string: "Button 1 initiated")

        let button2 = UIButton(type: .roundedRect)
        button2.frame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 60, width: 100, height: 30)
        button2.setTitle("NewCrash", for: [])
        button2.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.crashButtonTapped1(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        view.addSubview(button2)
        CLSLogv("Button2", getVaList([10,20]))
        write(string: "Button 2 initiated")

    }
    @IBAction func crashButtonTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        Crashlytics.sharedInstance().crash()
    }

    @IBAction func crashButtonTapped1(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        var i = [0,1,2,3]
        for k in i{
            print(10/k)
        }
    }

    func write(string: String) {
        CLSLogv("Button", getVaList([string]))
    }



    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. We are aware of an issue with multiline logs that appears to be affecting you. Please look to an upcoming version bump of our SDK to correct this.